Characterising extrema with weak derivatives
Let $u\in H^1(U)\cap C(\overline U),$ where $U$ is a connected open set. Then, what can we say about $Du$ in a neighbourhood of a maximum $x_0$ of $u$ on $\overline U?$
I have never seen a discussion of this so I wonder if we could get something reasonably nice.
